# Can a class instance know if it's an argument?

Tags: python, class, properties, arguments

Can an instance of a class know if it's being used as an argument, whether it's a positional or keyword argument, and if positional, which position it's in, and if keyword, which keyword it's assigned to, and following all of this, can it resolve to/return/replace itself with something else based on that knowledge, e.g. one of its instance properties, so the call gets that as an argument instead of the class instance itself?

I realize my class questions are getting crazier. Thanks for humoring me.

Comment: No. You can, however, implement methods to automatically convert the class to an other value (integer or string for example) in the corresponding context.

Comment: Crazy questions are probably an implication of a crazy design...

Answer (score 3):

no - none of that is possible.

trying to think how you might get close - you could define a decorator that loops over the arguments to a function and tells the arguments this information.

```
def toldargs(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kargs):
        for i, arg in enumerate(args):
            arg.you_are_arg_number(i)
        for k in kargs:
            kargs[k].you_are_karg_named(k)
        return f(*args, **kargs)
    return wrapper

@toldargs
def myfunction(a, b):
    ...
```

(uncompiled/untested).

this is going to affect performance significantly if you use it on functions that are often called.  and you'd likely need some kind of try/catch or instance test before calling the methods, to avoid errors with arguments that aren't expecting such a call.

**update** - thinking some more, you (probably) don't really care about when something is passed to a function, but what the context is when some operation on your instance is invoked (if an arg is passed to a function but never used, then it doesn't matter, in any case i can think of).

in other words:

```
def some_function(a, b):
    # here you can't trigger anything
    ...
    a.foo() # but here you can
```

when `.foo()` is called you can inspect your context.  there are various approaches - the most obvious/crude is throwing an exception, catching it, and examining the call stack.  but you can also use all the tools [here](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#the-interpreter-stack).  so, for example, you can inspect the current stack to see if you are being called from inside a particular class.

again, this is likely going to be slow and complicated...

**update 2** - see [Python: Modifying passed arguments before class instance initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522431/python-modifying-passed-arguments-before-class-instance-initialization) for a metaclass-based approach.

Comment: Thanks, andrew. The tricky bit here is that the functions my instance could be used in aren't written by me, and can't be modified by me. My class instance is a hierarchy, but is easily considered a single concept. I wanted the freedom to simply use the name of the instance everywhere, with most things not being caught by me simply receiving the class, as any function in Python would, but with the few things I know about, which require some subpart of the hierarchy, I wanted it to intelligently offer the right sub part. I can of course specify the sub part, but it's nice not to have to.

Comment: i don't really follow the details, but that made me think of another possible solution - see update above.

Comment: Yeah, I had been wondering if I might do something with inspect. This is definitely crossing into the realm of crazy code that I don't want to visit upon the world, but it's still fun to see what's possible, and I always learn a lot about the core of Python with these explorations. Thanks for your help, Andrew.