# Python: Modifying passed arguments before class instance initialization

Tags: python, oop, multiple-inheritance, metaclass

I am experimenting with ways to implement a simplified Term Rewriting System (TRS)/Symbolic Algebra System in Python.
For this I would really like to be able to be able to intercept and modify the operands in particular cases during the class instance instantiation process.
The solution I came up with, was to create a metaclass that modifies the typical **call** behavior of a class object (of type 'type').

```
class Preprocess(type):
    """
    Operation argument preprocessing Metaclass.
    Classes using this Metaclass must implement the 
        _preprocess_(*operands, **kwargs)
    classmethod.
    """

    def __call__(cls, *operands, **kwargs):
        pops, pargs = cls._preprocess_(*operands, **kwargs)
        return super(Preprocess, cls).__call__(*pops, **pargs)
```

An example case would be to expand out nested operations F(F(a,b),c)-->F(a,b,c)

```
class Flat(object):
    """
    Use for associative Operations to expand nested 
    expressions of same Head: F(F(x,y),z) => F(x,y,z)
    """
    __metaclass__ = Preprocess
    @classmethod
    def _preprocess_(cls, *operands, **kwargs):
        head = []
        for o in operands:
            if isinstance(o, cls):
                head += list(o.operands)
            else:
                head.append(o)
        return tuple(head), kwargs
```

So, now this behavior can be realized through inheritance:

```
class Operation(object):
    def __init__(self, *operands):
        self.operands = operands

class F(Flat, Operation):
    pass
```

This leads to the desired behavior:

```
print F(F(1,2,3),4,5).operands
(1,2,3,4,5)
```

However, I would like to combine several such preprocessing classes and have them process the operands sequentially according to the natural class mro.

```
class Orderless(object):
    """
    Use for commutative Operations to bring into ordered, equivalent 
    form: F(*operands) => F(*sorted(operands))
    """
    __metaclass__ = Preprocess

    @classmethod
    def _preprocess_(cls, *operands, **kwargs):

        return sorted(operands), kwargs
```

And this does not seem to work as wanted. Defining a Flat and Orderless Operation type

```
class G(Flat, Orderless, Expression):
    pass
```

results in only the first Preprocessing superclass being 'active'.

```
print G(G(3,2,1),-1,-3).operands
(3,2,1,-1,-3)
```

How can I ensure that all Preprocessing classes' *preprocess* methods are called before class instantiation?

Update:

I can't seem to formally answer my question yet due to my status as new stackoverflow user.
So, I believe this is probably the best solution I can come up with:

```
class Preprocess(type):
    """
    Abstract operation argument preprocessing class.
    Subclasses must implement the 
        _preprocess_(*operands, **kwargs)
    classmethod.
    """

    def __call__(cls, *operands, **kwargs):
        for cc in cls.__mro__:
            if hasattr(cc, "_preprocess_"):
                operands, kwargs = cc._preprocess_(*operands, **kwargs)

        return super(Preprocess, cls).__call__(*operands, **kwargs)
```

I guess the problem is that `super(Preprocess, cls).__call__(*operands, **kwargs)` does not traverse the mro of cls as expected.

Comment: Override the allocator and have it examine the bases.

Comment: Hm, how would that work exactly? Printing out the __bases__ of the cls object in the Preprocess.__call__ method yields (as expected)

    (<class '__main__.Flat'>, <class '__main__.Orderless'>,<class '__main__.Operation'>)

Comment: You need to return an object of a dynamic type. Which is why you do it in the allocator.

Comment: By allocator, do you mean the the "__new__()" method?
I was doing this before, but the problem with that is, if I change the operands in the new method, but return an object of the same type, the constructor (init) receives the original unprocessed operands as its arguments...

Comment: Which is why you return an object of a whole new type.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams But how could that even work for the simple example outlined above? If I want to flatten a nested structure of F(args_with_Fs), the ultimately returned type has to be F. What I have tried before was to simply call the _preprocess_ from both the __new__ method and the __init__ method, but that seems very inefficient, especially for large numbers of operands. 
Is it generally agreed upon that the allocator should only interfere with object creation if it produces a whole new type?

Comment: The entire purpose of the allocator is to produce a whole new type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going about this the wrong way; drop the metaclass, use class and method decorators instead.

For example, define your flat as:

```
@init_args_preprocessor
def flat(operands, kwargs): # No need for asterisks
    head = []
    for o in operands:
        if isinstance(o, cls):
            head += list(o.operands)
        else:
            head.append(o)
    return tuple(head), kwargs
```

With the init_args_preprocessor decorator turning that function into a class decorator:

```
def init_args_preprocessor(preprocessor):
    def class_decorator(cls):
        orig_init = cls.__init__
        def new_init(self, *args, **kwargs):
            args, kwargs = preprocessor(args, kwargs)
            orig_init(self, *args, **kwargs)
        cls.__init__ = new_init
        return cls
   return class_decorator
```

And now, instead of mixins use decorators:

```
class Operation(object):
    def __init__(self, *operands):
        self.operands = operands

@flat
class F(Operation):
    pass
```

And you should have no problem combining the class modifiers cleanly:

```
@init_args_preprocessor
def orderless(args, kwargs):
    return sorted(args), kwargs

@orderless
@flat
class G(Expression):
   pass
```

Caveat Emptor: All code above strictly untested.

Comment: Hi, yes that looks like a very nice solution and it turns out I am actually now doing something along those lines. One issue with this is that the object 'G' will not be a class anymore but rather a function, so isinstance() checks will fail without further tweaking.

Comment: Why is `G` a function? It is only modified by class decorators. `@init_args_preprocessor` turns `flat` into a function that takes a class and returns a class.

Comment: My bad, you are correct. This is, in fact, exactly the way I ended up doing it.